# Can someone explain Grothendieck schemes in layman language

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, grothendieck-topologies

Grothendieck Schemes are one of the key foundations of algebraic geometry which has been used in other fields as well Can anybody explain it in layman language?
I just want the idea and not the mathematical equations involved

Comment: You want mathematics without mathematics involved? Read [this nice essay](http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/07-08/Spring/18.726/l_1.pdf), it gives a good idea, I think.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I mean not the rigorous mathematics in it but just idea of the theory and it's applications

Comment: Yes, sure, just joking. How do you like the text?

Comment: @DietrichBurde the text?

Comment: Yes, the one I have linked above: "Why schemes?"

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have read this and another article written by David Mumford on Grothendieck's work.

Comment: @DietrichBurde are you aware of any other good text regarding the subject?

Comment: @DietrichBurde or can you explain it in your own words

Comment: There are many good texts, yes. The text says the most important things. We are generalising varieties for various reasons and aspects. So the first thing is to view several examples of algebraic varieties. I think you need examples to get some intuition. And a bit more of mathematics, of course.

Comment: What does "layman" mean?  Do you know what a ring is?  What a variety is?  Or do you literally want something that assumes no more than high school math?

Comment: @EricWofsey high school math level

Comment: High schoolers have  no need to know what a scheme is. With varieties there is plenty for them!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think that the kind of vague curiosity the OP is expressing is actually appropriate – it would be different if they were looking for a textbook reference with this kind of background, but it seems like they've come across the word "scheme" in the periphery of their pop math reading and want it to be less than completely black-boxed. On the other hand, I can't claim any authority on matters of pedagogy, so I'm genuinely curious to know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm upgrading my comment to an answer because I think it seems to fit what you're looking for. This comes with the obvious disclaimer that, without knowing the definition of rings, ideals, etc., one can really not expect to understand schemes with any clarity. With that said, a good introduction to the idea of schemes can be found in the Princeton Companion to Mathematics, Chapter IV.$5$, by Jordan Ellenberg (see [here](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/pdf/4662)). The maximally non-rigorous part, which assumes no background beyond basic English grammar, is section $3.1.$, but if you're curious about these things you should really try to palate some of the equations, which Ellenberg presents in a very accessible way.